# detect vessels in skin images using image processing

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I've been trying to retrieve blood vessels from skin  cancer images using image processing and the output is not accurate enough.  this is the code I used

```
def extract_bv(image):      
b,green_,r = cv2.split(image)
clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=2.0, tileGridSize=(8,8))
contrast_enhanced_green_ = clahe.apply(green_)

# applying alternate sequential filtering (3 times closing opening)
r1 = cv2.morphologyEx(contrast_enhanced_green_, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(5,5)), iterations = 1)
R1 = cv2.morphologyEx(r1, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(5,5)), iterations = 1)
r2 = cv2.morphologyEx(R1, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(11,11)), iterations = 1)
R2 = cv2.morphologyEx(r2, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(11,11)), iterations = 1)
r3 = cv2.morphologyEx(R2, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(23,23)), iterations = 1)
R3 = cv2.morphologyEx(r3, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(23,23)), iterations = 1)    
f4 = cv2.subtract(R3,contrast_enhanced_green_)
f5 = clahe.apply(f4)

# removing very small contours through area parameter noise removal
ret,f6 = cv2.threshold(f5,15,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY) 
mask = np.ones(f5.shape[:2], dtype="uint8") * 255   
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(f6.copy(),cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for cnt in contours:
    if cv2.contourArea(cnt) <= 200:
        cv2.drawContours(mask, [cnt], -1, 0, -1)            
im = cv2.bitwise_and(f5, f5, mask=mask)
ret,fin = cv2.threshold(im,15,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)            
newfin = cv2.erode(fin, cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(3,3)), iterations=1)   

# removing blobs of unwanted bigger chunks taking in consideration they are not straight lines like blood
#vessels and also in an interval of area
im_eroded = cv2.bitwise_not(newfin) 
xmask = np.ones(im.shape[:2], dtype="uint8") * 255
xcontours, xhierarchy = cv2.findContours(im_eroded.copy(),cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)    
for cnt in xcontours:
    shape = "unidentified"
    peri = cv2.arcLength(cnt, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.04 * peri, False)                  
    if len(approx) > 4 and cv2.contourArea(cnt) <= 3000 and cv2.contourArea(cnt) >= 100:
        shape = "circle"    
    else:
        shape = "veins"
    if(shape=="circle"):
        cv2.drawContours(xmask, [cnt], -1, 0, -1)   

finimage = cv2.bitwise_and(im_eroded,im_eroded,mask=xmask)  
blood_vessels = cv2.bitwise_not(finimage)
return blood_vessels
```

and these are the results.

original and output
[image: original]
[image: output]
expected
[image: expected]

Any suggestions how can I improve this? Thank You

Comment: You’re looking for vessels, you need to use a filter that is sensitive to elongated structures. None of your filtering does that. Take a look, for example, at [Fragi vesselness](https://www.google.com/search?q=frangi+vesselness) filter.